# Extract portfolio pdf with large no of pdfs in it

Tags: java, pdf, itext, portfolio

I have a portfolio PDF with folders, subfolders and files. I need to extract the same structure  using iText in java. I am not able to extract portfolio pdfs with large no of pdfs in it. With small no of pdfs its working fine.

Please find the code that I am using.

```
public void extractPortfolio(String src) {
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();

    PdfDictionary names = root.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
    System.out.println("****names names *********" + names.getKeys().toString());
    PdfDictionary embedded = names.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
    System.out.println("####embedded embedded ########" + embedded.toString());

    PdfArray filespecs =null; 
    filespecs=embedded.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);//all pdfs  null in case of large no of pdfs

    for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.size();) {
        try {
            extractAttachment(reader, folders, folder, filespecs.getAsString(i++), filespecs.getAsDict(i++));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
protected  void extractAttachment(PdfReader reader, Map<Integer, File> dirs, File dir, PdfString name, PdfDictionary filespec) throws IOException {
    PRStream stream;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    String filename;
    PdfDictionary refs = filespec.getAsDict(PdfName.EF);

    File dirHere = dir;
    String nameString = name.toUnicodeString();

    if (nameString.startsWith("<")) {

        int closing = nameString.indexOf('>');

        if (closing > 0) {
            int folderId = Integer.parseInt(nameString.substring(1, closing));
            File folderFile = dirs.get(folderId); 
            System.out.println("Folder Fiel>>>"+folderFile.getName());
            if (folderFile != null) {
                dirHere = folderFile;

            }
        }
    }

    for (PdfName key : refs.getKeys()) {
        stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(refs.getAsIndirectObject(key));

        filename = filespec.getAsString(key).toString();

        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dirHere, filename));
        fos.write(PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream));
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

In the code value of filespecs variable is coming null.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thankx for the reply.. please find the below link for PDF file  [link]            (https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=464EC333E3DD6FA5&resid=464EC333E3DD6FA5%21107&authkey=AEF0aYu1yy6iVXQ)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your code (which might be based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31875439/1729265) I gave) assumes that **(Catalog)** -> **Names** -> **EmbeddedFiles** immediately contains the **Names** array with the **Filespec** entries:

```
PdfDictionary names = root.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
System.out.println("****names names *********" + names.getKeys().toString());
PdfDictionary embedded = names.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
System.out.println("####embedded embedded ########" + embedded.toString());

PdfArray filespecs =null; 
filespecs=embedded.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);//all pdfs  null in case of large no of pdfs
```

This assumption is wrong. **(Catalog)** -> **Names** -> **EmbeddedFiles** is the root of a so-called *Name Tree*, and as a tree it may have **Kids** which once again may have **Kids** of their own etc. only eventually leading to a leaf node containing the **Names** array with the **Filespec** entries.

If you have a PDF with only a very few attachments, usually its **EmbeddedFiles** name tree is somewhat compressed, its root being also its only leaf node, and this is the situation your code and the code from [my former answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31875439/1729265) understands.

So your code needs to be enhanced to recurse here, not only look for **Names** in **EmbeddedFiles** but also for **Kids**, and inside them also not only look for **Names** but also for **Kids**, etc etc.

Comment: Thankx for the reply.. can u please correct my logic in code, in order to check Names array recursively. As m not able to do so.