# How to get number of pages of Portable Collection Pdf using IText or any function using Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile, new byte[0]);
pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
```

Suppose there are two pdfs(Each pdf contains 2 pages) inside portable collection. When i try to get number of pages it returns just 1. I think it is considering cover page of the portable collection document. Is there any way to get number of pages of portable colletion ?
I am using Java 11 and IText 5.5 version.

Comment: @mkl Any suggestions

Comment: Could the downvoters please comment ? Please upvote this.

Comment: Simply extract the contained documents, open them as individual PDFs in `PdfReader` instances, and query their respective page counts. Then add up.

Comment: I extracted the documents and got the total page count. I have two scenario one is normal pdf and other is Portable Collection pdf. How to check whether pdf is normal or Portable Collection pdf @mkl

Comment: Check for a **Collection** dictionary in the **Catalog** dictionary. *A collection dictionary specifies the viewing and organizational characteristics of portable collections. If this dictionary is present in a PDF document, the conforming reader shall present the document as a portable collection.*

Comment: PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog(); After this what is the code to be wriiten. Cannot find specific method. @mkl

Comment: @mkl look at above comment. Take a look at inefficient solution. Any way using Catalog...?

Comment: *"After this what is the code to be wriiten. Cannot find specific method."* - Look at `retrieveFolders` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31875439/1729265), this method also first checks for the existence of a **Collection** dictionary in the **Catalog** dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this but i think it is unnecessary to check the below things and solution is not a efficient way of getting the total pdf page numbers.

```
private int getNumberOfPages(PdfReader reader) {
            int pages = 0;
            PdfObject obj;
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
                obj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
                if (obj != null && obj.isStream()) {
                    PRStream stream = (PRStream)obj;
                    byte[] b;
                    try {
                        b = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
                        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(b);
                        pages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
                    } catch(InvalidPdfException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }

                }
            }
            if (pages == 0) {
                pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            }
            return pages;
        }
```

Comment: **Shock!!!**  *"I think the below solution is not a efficient way of getting the total pdf page numbers."* - This indeed is an overkill. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31875439/1729265) for example code for extracting files in a portfolio. (The code there is about extracting files in a portfolio with folders. For a solution also working with portfolios without folders, update `retrieveFolders` to return an empty `Map` instead of throwing an exception if there is no **Folders** entry.)

Comment: Is there any way to add unmodifiable metadatas to pdf ? I just want to protect the metadatas of pdf is it possible @mkl